# <Error>: GeezaPro: FT_Load_Glyph failed: error 6

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, xcode4.6

I have two view controllers in my application, when I use (segue) to push to the second view controller (detail view controller), I face this error :
: GeezaPro: FT_Load_Glyph failed: error 6.

this error displayed in the debug area while the detail view controller is opened.

Note: I don't have sharekit in my application.

can I know the reason of this error and how to fix it please